# How to number everything (sections, pages, figures, list items etc) starting at zero?

Tags: numbering

Like [Dijkstra](https://www.cs.utexas.edu/users/EWD/ewd08xx/EWD831.PDF), I believe one should count things starting at zero. How do I achieve zero-based numbering throughout in LaTeX for chapters, sections, figures, tables, pages, references, footnotes, equations, list items, lines, and whatever else there may be?

I'm using the memoir documentclass.

Comment: Use `\setcounter{chapter}{-1}`

Comment: I think you're reading Dijkstra in the wrong way. The chapter number is zero until a chapter starts, so it must be number 1. Another instance when numbering from 1 is right: when I talk about the sequence of vectors `$\{v_1;v_2;\dots;v_n\}$` I'm not excluding `$n=0$`, in which case the sequence is empty; `$n$` denotes *exactly* the number of vectors in the sequence.

Comment: @egreg it's over use of C it addles the mind:-)

Comment: @egreg I'm pretty sure Dijkstra means that the lowest-numbered element should have number zero. That's how he numbers his pages in the note I linked to, for instance, and he gives "0 ≤ _i_ < _N_" as an example of a good subscript range. In any case, that's how I want to do it.

Comment: @jolson And my example shows he's, with due respect, wrong.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\def\@arabic#1{\number\numexpr#1-1\relax}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\section{zzz}

aa
\begin{equation}1=0\end{equation}

\subsection{bbb}

zz
\begin{equation}1=0\end{equation}
\subsection{bbb}

\section{hhh}

\subsection{lll}

zz
\begin{figure}
\fbox{XXXXX}

\caption{zzz}
\end{figure}

\begin{enumerate}
\item zzz
\item 333
\item kkk
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

or with `memoir` and `\chapter`

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\makeatletter
\def\@arabic#1{\number\numexpr#1-1\relax}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\chapter{gg}
\section{zzz}

aa
\begin{equation}1=0\end{equation}

\subsection{bbb}

zz
\begin{equation}1=0\end{equation}
\subsection{bbb}

\section{hhh}

\subsection{lll}

zz
\begin{figure}
\fbox{XXXXX}

\caption{zzz}
\end{figure}

\begin{enumerate}
\item zzz
\item 333
\item kkk
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You beat me to it :)

Comment: Good choice to redefine only the arabic numerals -- I'd hate to think how one might go about adjusting Roman numerals and alphabetically labeled sequences...

Comment: @Mico exactly the same change (although romannumeral for 0 is empty so it may look a bit odd)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle - So, redefining `\@alph` will give an empty number for the letter immediately before "a"? :-)

Comment: @Mico yes if you just subtract 1 as above and rely on the `\ifcase` that `\@alph` uses. Alternativeively you could subtract one as above than the redefine `\@alph`  to put something before the first `\or` (whatever symbol you want for zero)

Comment: Thank you! This is amazing! I have confirmed that it also works with line numbers (using the "lineno" package), subfigures (using the "subcaption" package set to Arabic numbering), but fails for references (using the "biblatex" package). Would you know how to rectify that?